# Why do events have the “on” prefix in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Why do events have the `on` prefix, like `onclick`, for example:

```html
<button onclick="displayDate()">The time is?</button>
```

On W3Schools, it clearly states the `onclick` is an event, below is a screenshot:

[image]

But on MDN, it says that `click` is the event.

So my questions are:

- Which one is the true event, `onclick` or `click`?
- Why do we use `onclick` in HTML, but `click` in JavaScript, like this?

  ```js
  button.addEventListener('click', event => {
   ...;
  });
  ```

  Why not like this?

  ```js
  button.addEventListener('onclick', event => {
   ...;
  });
  ```

Comment: `onclick` describes the function that is executed __on__ a user `click`. In the `button.addEventListener` part you give a function to an event handler of the dom-element `button`. It is bound to the event type `click`.

Not sure how technically correct it is but anyways...

Comment: @Quentin plz check the screenshot in my post

Comment: @amjad . It's W3Schools. not W3C. There are many mistakes there.

Comment: W3Schools have nothing to do with the W3C. They chose the name to con people into thinking they are affiliated/the same.

Comment: Why? Because that's what [the spec says](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#events-mouseevents) apart from that an arbitrary decision made by some developer in the dim and distant past

Comment: @Turnip — I don't know if it was deliberate, but they've certainly benefited from that effect.

Comment: I'm making assumptions, but that has always been my take on it.

Comment: @Quentin sorry I thought w3schools is the official user friendly site of w3c. So can I say `onclick` is a html attribute?

Comment: The name of the event is the one that you’d get from the [`Event.prototype.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/type) getter: _“The name of the event (case-insensitive)”_. The only [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) starting with `on` is `online`, but of course not in the same sense of the `on` prefix. Trust MDN, not W3Schools.

Comment: @amjad _“The site derives its name from the World Wide Web (W3), but is not affiliated with the W3C.”_ — the [About section](https://www.w3schools.com/about/default.asp).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> which one is the true event, onclick or click?

`click` is the name of the event

`onclick` is the name of the property (and HTML attribute) to which you assign a function which will be called when the event is triggered

"on" is used in the sense "[Indicating the day or part of a day during which an event takes place](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/on).": At the time the event takes place, the function is called.

> why it is not
>
> ```
> button.addEventListener('onclick',
> ```

The meaning "when the event is triggered" is conveyed by "addEventListener" so it doesn't need to be conveyed again by saying "on".

Also, some elements have methods like `click()` and `focus()` which make things happen. You'd get a name clash if the event handler properties had the same names.